# How can I stringify a BSON object inside of a MongoDB map function?

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb, bson

I have documents with field `xyz` containing

```
{ term: "puppies", page: { skip: 1, per_page: 20 } } // not useful as a composite key...
{ page: { skip: 1, per_page: 20 }, term: "puppies" } // different order, same contents
```

For the sake of determining the "top" values in xyz, I want to map them all to something like

```
emit('term="puppies",page={ skip: 1, per_page: 20 }', 1); // composite key
```

but I can't get the embedded objects into a meaningful strings:

```
emit('term="puppies",page=[object bson_object]', 1); // not useful
```

Any suggestions for a function to use instead of `toString()`?

```
# return the top <num> values of <field> based on a query <selector>
#
# example: top(10, :xyz, {}, {})
def top(num, field, selector, opts = {})
  m = ::BSON::Code.new <<-EOS
    function() {

      var keys = [];

      for (var key in this.#{field}) {
        keys.push(key);
      }

      keys.sort ();

      var sortedKeyValuePairs = [];

      for (i in keys) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var value = this.#{field}[key];

        if (value.constructor.name == 'String') {
          var stringifiedValue = value;
        } else if (value.constructor.name == 'bson_object') {
          // this just says "[object bson_object]" which is not useful
          var stringifiedValue = value.toString();
        } else {
          var stringifiedValue = value.toString();
        }

        sortedKeyValuePairs.push([key, stringifiedValue].join('='));
      }

      // hopefully we'll end up with something like
      // emit("term=puppies,page={skip:1, per_page:20}")
      // instead of
      // emit("term=puppies,page=[object bson_object]")
      emit(sortedKeyValuePairs.join(','), 1);
    }
  EOS
  r = ::BSON::Code.new <<-EOS
    function(k, vals) {
      var sum=0;
      for (var i in vals) sum += vals[i];
      return sum;
    }
  EOS
  docs = []
  collection.map_reduce(m, r, opts.merge(:query => selector)).find({}, :limit => num, :sort => [['value', ::Mongo::DESCENDING]]).each do |doc|
    docs.push doc
  end
  docs
end
```

Comment: Going right up to the first code example. Why is that not useful as a composite key? MongoDB is perfectly capable of have BSON objects as _id (or keys).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that [MongoDB uses SpiderMonkey as its internal JS engine](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+Spider+Monkey), can't you use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (will work even if/when MongoDB [switches to V8](http://www.howsthe.com/blog/2010/feb/22/mongodb-and-v8/)) or SpiderMonkey's non-standard [`toSource` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource)?

(sorry, can't try it ATM to confirm it'd work)

Comment: JSON.stringify did not work for me in Mongo 2.0.6, but obj.toSource did. Thanks.

Comment: +Paul Wheeler you should make that into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[toSource method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) will do the work, but it adds also brackets.
for a clean document use:

```
value.toSource().substring(1, value.toSource().length - 1)
```